# What is the difference between "usar", "ponerse" and "vestir"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras, vocabulario, ropa

In Mexico we use any of this verbs with clothes vocabulary, but what is the difference between these verbs?

- usar
- vestir
- ponerse

Comment: ... and then there's *llevar puesto*....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some dialogue that can help show how they're often used.  Here we have a parent guiding a child in getting ready to go to school.

> Levántate, Juanito. Ya mero viene el autobús. ¡**Vístete** ya! ... Ay, ¿llevas [**puestos**] los calcetines de ayer?  Te los quitas, por favor.  Hay calcetines limpios en la cómoda, agarra, te los **pones**, muchas gracias. ... Hay que **usar** el abrigo, hace mucho frío hoy. ... ¡**Ponte** los guantes, hombre, mira, hay nieve!

Comment: I can see the difference, it like you say " ponte el sueter " or " usa un sueter" so the context I suppose is similar. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Roughly, "usar" means "to use". "Vestir" means "to wear", and "ponerse" means to "put on".

"Usar" is not very used in Spain, at least not in infinitve. However, you can use it as an adejctive. "Ropa usada", the one that you have already worn, either by you or another person. In any case, you might want to give it a wash.

On the other hand, "vestir" means "to wear", and it is linked to the present. If you wear something, you're taking it with you. [IT can also be a custom, you wear a certain kind of clothers, frequently, but that's a present tense anyways.]

Meanwhile, "ponerse" doesn't carry that "present tense" meaning. It is a punctual action, not continuous, in the sense that you put on clothes, and that's all. You have already put them on, and they stay there, for you to wear.

I mean, when you finish "putting it on", you start wearing it. Wearing it is something continuous, while putting on is just at the beginning.

Comment: I really appreciate your response , it is very useful for me @FGSUZ. I can make the difference .

Comment: your response is very useful for me. Your explanation is so clear. Thank you.